# Image not showing in IE but in Chrome, why?

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, browser

Several images on a site im working on are not showing in IE but works fine in Chrome. Can't figure out whats the problem, anyone knows?

Here is an example image that wont show up in IE, I get the small box with a red cross over.

Comment: It does show up for me (on IE9). Which version are you on?

Comment: 8, 64bit. But not showing up on IEtester either. Although if I resave the image with photoshop "save for web" they start working. It's my client that uploaded them, so maby I just have to ask her if she didn't save em correctly.

Comment: The image you linked to is [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmyk). IE < 9 does not support CMYK images.

Comment: Thanks :D didn't think of that, but of course that's correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending a lot time in searching the answer, I finally concluded that IE9 doesn't support 32bpp bitmap. You can test it by open your bitmap in paint and save it as 24 bit bitmap. Then open it in IE9, it will open.